# How to schedule task in java code

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks

I know how to schedule task in spring context:

```
  <task:scheduler id="taskScheduler" pool-size="1" />
  <task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="taskScheduler">
    <task:scheduled ref="jobWatcher" method="run" cron="*/10 * * * * ?" />
  </task:scheduled-tasks>
```

But cron of my task can by configured during runtime so I need to create task in java code. In spring docs: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/scheduling.html is something like this:

```
scheduler.schedule(task, new CronTrigger("* 15 9-17 * * MON-FRI"));
```

which is what I want but I have no idea how their create  scheduler in this example and what is his class. Please help

Answer (score 1):

Just three paragraph above in your link

```
public interface TaskScheduler {

    ScheduledFuture schedule(Runnable task, Trigger trigger);

    ScheduledFuture schedule(Runnable task, Date startTime);

    ScheduledFuture scheduleAtFixedRate(Runnable task, Date startTime, long period);

    ScheduledFuture scheduleAtFixedRate(Runnable task, long period);

    ScheduledFuture scheduleWithFixedDelay(Runnable task, Date startTime, long delay);

    ScheduledFuture scheduleWithFixedDelay(Runnable task, long delay);

}
```

so in `scheduler.schedule(task, new CronTrigger("* 15 9-17 * * MON-FRI"));`

- `scheduler` is an instance of `TaskScheduler`
- `task` is a Runnable

  ```
  Runnable exampleRunnable = new Runnable(){

      @Override
      public void run() {
          //To change body of implemented methods 
      }
  };
  ```

Comment: I still dont know how you creating instance of scheduler. U just write here interface

Comment: @hudi sorry for being rude, but what I wrote was 3 paragraphs above your link, so try to read a bit more, and maybe, you need to start with java basis.

Comment: I think you dont understand my question. You post here just interface. I need some instance which implement this interface

Comment: it is hard to search on javadoc http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/TaskScheduler.html look @ Implementing classes

Answer (score 1):

Unlike XML configuration or annotation configuration (where you can specify directly a method of a Spring managed bean), you need to create your own `Runnable` which will call your method.

Say you have the following managed bean:

```
@Component
public class SchedulingBean{
    public void doSomethingPeriodically(){
    }
}
```

and you want to run the method inside on a dynamic cron, you have (at least) three options:

Let `SchedulingBean` implement `Runnable` and call the `doSomehtingPeriodically` method from the run method

```
@Component
public class SchedulingBean implements Runnable{
    public void doSomethingPeriodically(){
}
@Override
public void run(){
    doSomethingPeriodically();
    }
}
```

Create a new (maybe anonymous) `Runnable` instance that calls the method from within the managed bean. This could be a little trickier, as you will need to get the reference to that bean from the Spring context.

Or create a new (maybe anonymous) `Runnable` instance that implements directly the needed functionality, without using a managed bean:

```
public class SchedulingBean implements Runnable{
    public void doSomethingPeriodically(){
    }
    @Override
    public void run(){
        doSomethingPeriodically();
    }
}
```

(note the missing `@Component`)